Flutter invalid-email FirebaseAuth exception
I have a problem when trying to sign up and enter credentials. I enter a valid email format test@test.com, and i get this exception : [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
here is my method addUser() i implemented:
Future<void> addUser(String nom, String prenom, String matricule, String email,
    String motDePasse) async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: motDePasse,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}

please help thank you in advance !
im new to flutter, i tried everything i could try.

Welcome to SO. It would help to know what email resolves to before it's passed to addUser. Can you output that string to console and then (per the answer) ensure it doesn't have any additional characters?

are you sure you're passing test@test.com as email? It's common to have this issue occurred due to extra whitespaces at the end. If that's the case, you can simply trim the String and use it.
Try the following code:
Future<void> addUser(String nom, String prenom, String matricule, String email,
    String motDePasse) async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email.trim(), // <- trimmed the string
      password: motDePasse,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
}

Hope this helps :)
